# How to extract a subset of @_?

Tags: arrays, perl, subset

I have the following function that works. But I am not sure what is the best way to extract a subset of `@_`. How to extract a subset from `@_` in the best way?

```
sub parseheader {
  my $grps_len = shift;
  my @grps;

  for ( my $i = 0; $i < $grps_len; ++$in) {
    my $x = shift;
    print "$x\n";
    push(@grps, $x);
  }

  return join(",", @grps), "\n";
}

print parseheader(3, "a", "b", "c");
```

Answer (score 3):

With an array slice:

```
my @grps = @_[0..($grps_len-1)];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list or array slice.

```
sub parseheader { join(",", @_[ 1 .. $_[0] ]) . "\n" }

print parseheader(3, @things);
```

but I'd use

```
sub take_first { @_[ 1 .. $_[0] ] }

say join ",", take_first(3, @things);
```

---

If you want to remove the elements returned, you can use `splice`.

```
say join ",", splice(@things, 0, 3);
```

---

By the way,

```
for (my $i=0; $i < $grps_len; ++$i)
```

is a slow and complicated way of writing

```
for my $i (0..$grps_len-1)
```